# Output voltage of powerbank circuit is the same as the battery voltage

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, 5v

I'm trying to use this small (and awesome?) unit as a boost/step-up converter for my project. I need to give my ESP8266 12-E NodeMCU a 5v input from a 18650 battery. Since this powerbank already had 1x 18650 battery in it, I assumed doing this would be easy. I was wrong.

The circuit looks like this:

[image]

On the far right, you can see the micro USB input, which charges the battery (B+ and B-) at 4.2v. In the middle, you can see 4 solder pads. [That is a regular female USB connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxCKZ.jpg), which I desoldered.

Here's the weird issue: If I take my battery, which is at 3.8v at the moment, and I check the voltage on the USB in the middle (which would normally charge your phone), it will be at 3.8v as well.

Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't it be 5v, so it would charge my other devices at 5v? You can see the complete unit here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdSv2.jpg

Comment: It is difficult (or impossible) to tell what this unit is from the picture. Do you have a link to where you bought it, or a model number/name?

Comment: @RonBeyer Yeah, I figured someone would ask. Nope, I don't know what kind of unit it is or where to get one today. It was inside a cheap, cheap, cheap 1 cell powerbank I got years ago. The album at the bottom shows the other side of the unit, which might help a bit.

Comment: Do you have a load connected, when you are measuring the Voltage? If I were making this sort of circuit, I would want feedback from the o/p load. With no load, you would just see the V i/p. Which IC device is on that board? Knowing what the IC is, you could get the data sheet, which should show a reference cct.

Comment: Please post the schematic for this device.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Before I do anything else, do you think the voltage could increase, if I put some load on it? Is that actually a possibility?

Comment: Nevermind, I just soldered my LED strip to it and it's at 3.5v right now. Not 5v.

Comment: The IC is a FM6316FE.

Comment: @NickAlexeev I don't have that, but it looks like [this one](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2017/05/01/powerbank-with-dummy-batteries/) with an FM6316FE IC.